# Convert multiple columns in pandas dataframe to array of arrays

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
   col1  col2  col3 
1     1     2     3    
2     4     5     6  
3     7     8     9    
4     10    11    12
```

I want to create a new column that will be an array of arrays, that contains a single array consisting of specific columns, casted to float.
So given column names, say "col2" and "col3", the output dataframe would look like this.

```
   col1  col2  col3        new
1     1     2     3    [[2,3]]
2     4     5     6    [[5,6]]
3     7     8     9    [[8,9]]
4     10    11    12   [[11,12]]
```

What I have so far works, but seems clumsy and I believe there's a better way. I'm fairly new to pandas and numpy.

```
selected_columns = ["col2", "col3"]
df[selected_columns] = df[selected_columns].astype(float)
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda r: tuple(r[selected_columns]), axis=1) 
              .apply(np.array) 
              .apply(lambda r: tuple(r[["new"]]), axis=1) 
              .apply(np.array)
```

Appreciate your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
cols = ['col2', 'col3']
df['new'] = df[cols].agg(list, axis=1)
```

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
df['new'] = df[cols].to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3       new
1     1     2     3    [2, 3]
2     4     5     6    [5, 6]
3     7     8     9    [8, 9]
4    10    11    12  [11, 12]
```

##### 2D lists

```
cols = ['col2', 'col3']
df['new'] = df[cols].agg(lambda x: [list(x)], axis=1)

# or
df['new'] = df[cols].to_numpy()[:,None].tolist()
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3         new
1     1     2     3    [[2, 3]]
2     4     5     6    [[5, 6]]
3     7     8     9    [[8, 9]]
4    10    11    12  [[11, 12]]
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, I need the 'new' column to be an array that contains an array, like [[2, 3]] instead of  [2, 3], could you advise on that?